Sampling without replacement - dependent or independent?
I sampled without replacement. I sampled individual animals across several time points. I want to know whether there is statistical difference over time in the abundance of viral infections in the animal populations. The populations are large enough that in theory the removal of the animals in each time point should not influence the outcome.
Should I treat this data as independent or dependent?

It depends on what you mean by "data," on what your probability model is (assuming you are using "independent" in the standard sense within probability theory), and on what you mean by "treat."  Could you provide more information?

I want to see if there's statistically significant difference in the abundance of viral infections in an animals species over time. I used a Kruskal-Wallis test because 1) cannot assume normality, 2) I treated my temporal abundance data as independent. I did this because the population size is large and ~6 years passed between time points, so I assumed that the removal of animals would not have an impact on probabilities. However, I am comparing viral abundance data across the same animal population, even if dif individuals, so should I treat it as dependent use something other than KW?

I can't respond to that, because the details of your sampling are unclear.  In particular, does "sampled individual animals across ... time points" mean that you observed the same set of animals over multiple of times (a longitudinal study) or separate sets of animals each time?  It's also unclear whether by "probabilities" you are referring to modeled probabilities, such as chance of viral infection, or sampling probabilities, referring to chances of being included in a sample.

I sampled without replacement -- so it is the same animal species from the same general locality, but different individuals were collected (the animals are dissected) in each year.

So I am just wondering if I want to know if there is a statistically significance in the abundance of viruses in the animals through time (again, sampled without replacement but from the same species at the same general location), what type of test would be appropriate?

By "abundance" of viral infections would you mean proportion of animals in the population with at least one infection?  If so, this sounds like a two-sample test of proportions.  But if it's something else, such as counts of infections found in each animal, a different analysis is called for.
